# Why is TFTP 'PUT' failing on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, networking, ftp, tftp

I am using Windows 7 RTM, and things are running smoothly for the most part. My Windows 7 installation is the default, out of the box configuration.

I am using the standard TFTP utility available with Windows 7. When I attempt to upload a 3 kb text file to our internal TFTP server, it always time's out. However, TFTP'ing the same file, on XP (from the same network port --- different laptop, but same model) it works perfectly.

Is anyone aware of any default configuration on Windows 7 (or even) Vista that could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue may be with the network card driver. I'll wait until an official Windows 7 driver is released for my Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit NIC.

Comment: Turned out it was my 3rd party firewall disabling this traffic. Kind of a dumb mistake on my part, but I wanted to post the root cause here in case someone runs into the same problem/oversight.

Answer (score 3):

There is a warning at the [**DD-WRT TFTP-Flash** page](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Tftp_flash) that might be useful.

> Recommendations - In order to catch the narrow window for TFTP flash, you should use platforms with simple TCP/IP implementations that don't have [CTCP implemented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_TCP): WinXP or Linux are reported to work, but **some are reporting significant problems with Vista, Windows 7 or Windows 2008**.

Can you consider using the `FTP` client?
you would need a FTP server rather than a TFTP server at the other end.

---

According the the Wikipedia page, the following is supposed to disable CTCP,

```
netsh interface tcp set global congestionprovider=none
```

---

However, what I fail to understand is -- [TFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol) uses UDP rather than TCP,
So, I don't get how the CTCP problem is related to TFTP.